# How does a person become a godparent in the Roman Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, godparents

Assume a young adult is close to Confirmation in the Roman Catholic church, but, while still a child, never finishes the process because the family moves away from the parish.  What would be the process for this person to become a godparent at this point in the Roman Catholic church? Would it matter if the person in question is the sibling of one of the birth parents?

Comment: Although the Stacks Exchange cannot really give personal advice, I think this question can be generalized into "Can an unconfirmed person in the Catholic church be a godparent?"

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it seems the OP is looking for the Catholic answer to: "What must a young adult do to become a Godparent in the Catholic Church. If you don't mind, Kate, I am going to edit this. If you don't like it you can revert back to the original or edit it to something else.

Comment: @fredsbend It's been edited.

Comment: @Anonymous I edited it too. My edit is the one that took. Sorry if I messed this up for someone else.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Catholic Church's Code of Canon Law - [Canon 874 §1.](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2Y.HTM) states that in order for someone to be permitted to take on the function of sponsor (godparent) a person must:

> 1/ be designated by the one to be baptized, by the parents or the
>   person who takes their place, or in their absence by the pastor or
>   minister and have the aptitude and intention of fulfilling this
>   function;
>
> 2/ have completed the sixteenth year of age, unless the diocesan
>   bishop has established another age, or the pastor or minister has
>   granted an exception for a just cause;
>
> 3/ be a Catholic who has been confirmed and has already received the
>   most holy sacrament of the Eucharist and who leads a life of faith in
>   keeping with the function to be taken on;
>
> 4/ not be bound by any canonical penalty legitimately imposed or
>   declared;
>
> 5/ not be the father or mother of the one to be baptized.
>
> §2. A baptized person who belongs to a non-Catholic ecclesial
>   community is not to participate except together with a Catholic
>   sponsor and then only as a witness of the baptism.

In conclusion - to address your question more specifically, it must be clearly noted that:

(A) The godparent must *definitely* be confirmed in the faith, both sacramentally as well as proactively.

(B) The godparent must be over the age of 16 *unless given a special dispensation by the local bishop*.

If this question actually pertains to you or someone you know, my advice would be to contact your local priest...he *should* have all the answers to questions pertaining to sacraments.

Comment: Good answer, but you might want to spell it out that "yes, you do need to be confirmed" if I'm reading this correctly. I had to read it twice to find that little part.

Comment: Not only that, but they have to be sixteen, and "a young person close to Confirmation" may not be. (It's not clear in the question whether age is material.)